# Can't inject $location inside app.config

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to inject the $location and AppConstant (factory) values inside of config block.

```
app.config(['RestangularProvider', function (RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/san/');


    RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(function (response, deferred, responseHandler) {

        if (response.status > 400) {
            //ERROR - can't inject
            angular.injector().invoke(['AppConstant', '$location', function () {
                AppConstant.redirectUrl = $location.path();
                $location.path('/signin');
            }]);
        //
            return false; // error handled
        }

        return true; // error not handled
    });


}]);
```

But I am not injecting directly into config, I am trying to inject in middle of config on some function scope only.

Please help me to understand the angular and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, it says that:

> The ng module must be explicitly added.

You are using it like this: `angular.injector().invoke(...`
But you should be using it like this: `angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(...`

This is typical usage:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
$injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile, $document) {
    $compile($document)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Here are the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector)

Comment: The below itself throwing error: from console.
Please Help me to understand..
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
$injector.invoke(['$location', function($location){}]);

Comment: If you provide a bit more of your code and the error itself, I might be able to help.